# Issue adding multiple Polygon objects to canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, addchild

I currently programming the classic arcade game Asteroids in C# WPF to get some practice. 
I have run into an issue that I cannot seem to solve.

I am running into issues while generating asteroids and adding to the canvas element which contains all of my game objects.

I have a generateAsteroids method that gets called every 20 milliseconds along over methods that update the player ships position and so on. generateAsteroids method performs various calculations (comments in function) to determine how many asteroids to add to the asteroidCollection list. This all works fine.

The issue arises when I try to add the asteroids Polygon object to the games canvas.

I get the following error: "ArugementException was unhandled by user code: Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget"

Now I understand what this means (I think), all of the Asteroid objects are called "asteroid" which obviously is not ideal, Ive researched and found that you cannot dynamically create variable names for objects on the fly.

I have tried giving the Polygon a dynamic name each time one gets added to the canvas.

Can anyone in the know of this issue please help me out?

Ive added all the code that I think is relevant, please let me know if you need to see more.

Thanks

C#:

```
public void drawAsteroid(Asteroid theAsteroid)
{
    // entityShape is a Polygon object
    theAsteroid.entityShape.Name = "asteroid" + this.asteroidsAdded.ToString();
    theAsteroid.entityShape.Stroke = Brushes.White;
    theAsteroid.entityShape.StrokeThickness = 2;
    theAsteroid.entityShape.Points = theAsteroid.getEntityDimensions();
    gameCanvas.Children.Add(theAsteroid.entityShape);
}

// Called every 20 milliseconds by method that updates the game canvas. Possibly quite inefficient 
public void generateAsteroids()
{
    // Number of asteroids to add to the collection = the length of the game so far / 3, then subtract the amount of asteroids that have already been added
    int asteroidNum = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((DateTime.Now - gameStartTime).TotalSeconds / 3));
    asteroidNum -= asteroidsAdded;

    for (int i = 0; i <= asteroidNum; i ++)
    {
        asteroidCollection.Add(new Asteroid());
        this.asteroidsAdded += 1;
    }

    foreach (Asteroid asteroid in asteroidCollection)
    {
        drawAsteroid(asteroid);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="GameWindow" x:Class="AsteroidsAttempt2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="1000" Height="1000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Loaded="GameWindow_Loaded">

<Canvas x:Name="GameCanvas" Focusable="True" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1000" KeyDown="GameCanvas_KeyDown"  KeyUp="GameCanvas_KeyUp">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="D:\CPIT\BCPR283\Asteroids\Asteroids\AsteroidsAttempt2\Resources\SpaceBackground.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

In each call of the `drawAsteroid` method you're adding all Polygons from the `asteroidCollection` to the Canvas, regardless if they have already been added or not. But you can't add the same object twice to the `Children` collection of a WPF Panel. That's why you get the exception (it has nothing to do with the `Name`).

Change your code like this:

```
if (!gameCanvas.Children.Contains(theAsteroid.entityShape))
{
    gameCanvas.Children.Add(theAsteroid.entityShape);
}
```

Of course the code still lacks logic to remove Polygons from the Canvas that are no longer contained in the `asteroidCollection`. You will also have to add that.

---

And you don't need to set the `Name` of the Polygon objects at all, unless you want to access them by their name later.